# Could I make an application with java and python gui both using at same time?yes then how?

Tags: java, python, button, jframe

I am curious to know that can we combine both the languages and their toolkit to make an app. Could I make a jframe in java and add button in it through python code. Could i call java public classes and methods in a  .py  file and vice-versa?

Comment: Why an downvote?

Comment: because this is a very broad and poor question. answer these questions before you will get an answer here: why do you want to do that? what have you tried so far? have you tried to find any information on that topic yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Python implementation running on the JVM, called [Jython](http://www.jython.org/). If you use it to run your Python code, then yes, you'll be able to use Python to add buttons to a JFrame, or to call Java methods from a .py file.